# Access to private field another class from specialized class

Tags: c++11

I have 2 classes, one is specialized.
In the specialized class **Class_second** I would like to use private field *server* from **Class_first**.
The constructor **Class_first** creates server connection and I would like to use this in another specialized classes.

```
class Class_first {
    friend class Class_second<Message>;

    Class_first() : server(create_conn(ip, port){

    }

...

private:
    unique_ptr<Server> server;

};
```

This is one of few specialized classes.

```
template<>
class Class_second<T> {
public:

    void foo(T) {
        Class_first.server.get();   //this is wrong, how to correct it
        ...
    }
};
```

How I can obtain access to the server field of **Class_first** object. What is the best way to use it?

Possibly how I can return the reference to the server and use it in **Class_second**?

Comment: `How I can obtain access to the server field of Class_first object.` For starters, you would need an actual object of type `Class_first`. I don't see any in your code.

Comment: Could you expand your code to the minimal example that compiles? Then we can get a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish.